# how to embed jitsi with my web application using REST API CALL?

Tags: api, rest, jitsi

I have made a web application which allows any user to chat using sockets. Now I want to use jitsi to make video calls.

All users on my application are authenticated users. When a user clicks on the call button in chat window, I want to launch Jitsi Meet Conference in a new window by using a REST API Call.

Any guidance or pointers in the right directions is highly appreciated.

Comment: so after some digging, I have found this Jitsi Meet API - https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/api.md#jitsi-meet-api.

Working on a demo to use this API.

Comment: Hi nadeem. I have the same dilemma as you. How did you integrate it eventually.

Answer (score 5):

For embbeded version you can follow this link and it should work perfectly if you have jitsi-meet running correctly on some domain (public or local):

https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/api.md

lib-jitsi-meet is API if you want to build your own UI and not use embbeded one.

Comment: Will lib-jiti-api come with the same backend features as the jitsi meet. Because the docker image of jitsi meet spawns some 3 servers- prosody, web snd conference focus. I intend to use the libjitsi meet with my django application but unclear on whether the above comes part of it. Also e2ee is default in jitsi meet.

Comment: Sorry I haven't used Jitsi or their libs any more after this year, was it 2016 ? :D

Comment: Apologies here too. Didn't see the date.

Answer (score 4):

Try and use the lib-jitsi-meet library. Jitsi Meet application is built on top of the same library. The library provides base functions to connect to Jitsi and embed the same in your custom application. By using the Jitsi Meet application API, you might not be able to customise your application to the way you want. You can follow the example at the following link:
https://github.com/jitsi/lib-jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/example/example.js

Comment: Hi ankit. I'm designing my video call app in flutter. I came across this plugin - https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet. I can't figure which api of jitsi it is using. Can you help. Is it lib-jitsi meet ?